# Python... Hide widget upon menu option selection - Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Working with Tkinter, I am trying to make a label disappear and another appear in its place when a specific option is selected  with MenuOption().  Can I accomplish this without the need of a "refresh" button?

updated with a sample of my code:

```
mGui = Tk()
mGui.geometry('570x130+700+200')
mGui.resizable(width = FALSE, height = FALSE)
mGui.title('Title')


mylist = ['henry', 'tom', 'phil']
someValue = StringVar()

mLabel = Label(text = 'name:  ').grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = E)

someMenu = OptionMenu(mGui, someValue, *mylist)
someMenu.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = W)
someMenu.config(width = 14, anchor = W)

mGui.mainloop()
```

So, if someMenu.get() == 'tom' i want to hide mLabel...

so i've added the following:

```
def something():
        print someValue.get()

mylist = ['henry', 'tom', 'phil']
someValue = StringVar()
someValue.trace('w', something)
```

and am getting TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable..  hmmmmm

Comment: grid...  I've searched around and found the grid_remove method, just not sure how to integrate it upon selection of an option..

Comment: Are you just wanting to change the text, or completely remove the label?

Comment: either or, prob more efficient to change the text but I haven't quite gotten that far yet (beginner programmer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a trace on `someValue`, which can call a function whenever the value changes. In that function you can do anything you want, including removing widgets.

This website has an example: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm

Comment: Turns out I was missing *args within something().  Now it works!  :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if someMenu.get == "tom":
    buttonName.pack()
else:
    buttonName.pack_forget()
```

Comment: Please also briefly explain the code to be more educative.

Comment: This may not work -- depending on how the widgets were originally layed out, the next time they are added, they may get added in a different place.

Comment: @BryanOakley Agreed. It was more less of a tip, he never declared how he created the button in the first place. This would be standard though.

Comment: @user3158670: tips are preferred in comments on Stack Overflow. Answers are for sure and complete quality posts.